# Exclude a link from an addClass script.... NEED HELP :-)

Tags: removeclass

I need to EXCLUDE a link from the selected class in this script.  Can anyone show me how to exclude a link with a .logo class?  Checkout the links and the logo for the home link:  [link text](http://www.erikrp.com/test.htm)

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$('a.panel').click(function () {

    $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');

    current = $(this);

    $('#wrapperQ').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);     

    return false;
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    resizePanel();
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use not function.

```
$('a.panel').not('.logo').click(function () {
  ...
});
```